# How to put Analog on screen control to main scene?

Tags: android, andengine

I have HorizontalOnScreenControl class which extends BaseOnScreenControl, it is the same as DigitalOnScreenControl, but it works only horizontal. It's working fine. But one of this parents is Scene, and I think that why we need to do `scene.setChildScene(mDigitalOnScreenControl)`.

Problem: when I want, for example, show popup and when I use `.setChildScene()` one more time, my control disappears. But if I try to add directly to main scene: `scene.AttachChild(mDigitalOnScreenControl)` than I can't touch it, it's is not working, but visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Camera.setHUD` instead of `Scene.setChildScene`.

Quoting from the `HUD.java` file:

> While you can add a HUD to Scene, you should not do so. HUDs are meant to be added to Cameras via Camera.setHUD(HUD).

If you need to add 2 or more HUDs, you can chain them this way (I have 2 HUDs in one of my games, and that's how I do it. Works fine)

```
hud2.setChildScene(hud3);
hud1.setChildScene(hud2);
camera.setHUD(hud1);
```

Now you can call `Scene.setChildScene` and your control won't disappear.

**General knowledge**: When AndEngine receives a touch event from the Android framework, the event passes through a list entities. If any of them consumes the event, it stops. The priorities are:

1. Camera's HUD (If exists)
2. Child scene (If exists)
3. Touch areas in the scene (If there are any)
4. `onSceneTouchEvent` method.

Now, in your problem, when you attach the control to the scene as a regular entity, it doesn't receive the priority it should (Controls - HUDs have a first priority). So the event was probably consumed before it even reached the control.

Comment: It is working but now I can't remove it from camera. GameController.camera.getHUD().detachSelf(); it is not working. I need to remove it, because now when level is finished and I am back to level select (getEngine.setScene(getSomeScene()) ), control is still on the screen. Probably, I can set visibility to false, but...

Comment: I don't think you can call the `detachSelf` method of a HUD, because it doesn't have a parent. You could use `detachSelf` on the HUD if you'd add it with `setChildScene`, but we know it's wrong. Use `GameController.camera.setHUD(null);` instead.